# android "hello world " error

Tags: android-emulator

I'm using Mac OS X, and I installed Eclipse for Java developers software to do Android programs, and I successfully installed ADT plugin. Now when I'm trying to run `hello world` program, which is in `developer.android.com` site, the following warning is being displayed:

```
Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using `NSQuickDrawView`, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of `QuickDraw` and move to `Quartz`.
```

and instead of displaying `hello world` my emulator is displaying just `android`

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator might take a relatively long time to start, during which it just displays the flashing android text. Have you given it enough time?

Comment: @llkka i had waited for 5 min